# oauth2 library for python2.3?

Tags: python, oauth

Does anyone know of an oauth2 library that works with python2.3?  I know python2.3 is a little dated but we still haven't updated yet :/

Most auth2 libraries I see say something like "Most likely doesn't work anymore with python2.3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this paid for library: http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Authentication/OAuth--Python-Library--65907.html

Disclaimer: I've not ever used it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Mike Knapp's library on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library).
Nice and simple, no install needed.